# C++ operator setter ruby style

Tags: c++, ruby, operators, overloading, setter

Why don't people code like this? Ruby style!

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Name {
    public:
        void operator=(char *to) {
            name = to;
            printf("Change!\n");
        }
    private:
        char *name;
};

class Human {
    public:
        //char *name;
        Name name;
};

int main() {
    Human andreas = Human();
    andreas.name = "Andreas";
    printf("%s\n", andreas.name);
}
```

Using public member functions until you need to add something to the setter. Then switch it out for a class with operator=.

Comment: Who says they don't?

Comment: Because having public data members violates encapsulation, for one.

Comment: @Andrew That’s begging the question.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: The problem with absolutes like that is there will always be instances in which they are wrong.  If you have a plain simple data type and you know that you will never need getters/setters make the variable public.  Adding "properties" around it does nothing but add bloat to your code.

Comment: @Kaz The difference is precisely that – syntax! Surely you cannot argue that both are equally readable …! They are definitely not. For an extreme example, consider any Java code (especially GUI scaffolds), and compare that to e.g. C#. If you code with lots of accessors, having a clearer syntax is a decisive advantage.

Comment: There is no need to change from public members to getters and setters, because you can write member objects which look like public members, but are actually getters and setters which inform the object (i.e. are methods). There is no inherent difference between public methods and public data: accessing something with syntax that looks like a data reference can trigger a method. Object-like accesses are just syntactic sugar for simple getter and setter methods. It looks like there is an encapsulation problem, if you associate "data" with simple types like `int` or classes like `std::string`.

Answer (score 3):

> Using public member functions until you need to add something to the setter. Then switch it out for a class with operator=.

Because if by the time you need to change it, your project has grown hundredfold and now you need to change code at a lot of different places – maybe even in other projects, if you’re shipping a library.

In other words, you break code. *A lot* of code.

And even if you don’t write a library now, there’s always the chance that you will reuse some piece of code in a more general setting. Don’t count on the fact that every piece of code will remain local use.

Apart from that, there’s no big incentive at all to provide an easy syntax for setters since setters are actually only rarely needed. Modern C++ strives to minimise changes to a created object. This makes it easier to reason about the state of objects and hence about the program state in general. This in turn decreases complexity, bugs and maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

Such a switch breaks the interface, something you usually want to avoid.